# Problems with Ubuntu Center

Tags: software-center

I have two problems with Ubuntu Center.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which is installed on USB Flash Drive 3.0.

### 1.After installing Ubuntu

, Software Center looks strange. I used to use Ubuntu few years ago and compared to software center I remember, software center on my new computer looks like old and outdated(Actually, some software was even missing! Maybe I had done something wrong while installing).
Software Center on my new computer looks like this:
[image: Old, outdated Software Center?]
I installed new software center, and It looks like this:
[image]
So, do I have old software center? or I'm just confusing old and new one?

### 2.Newly installed Ubuntu Center won't open

after next boot. Reinstalling solved this, but problem happens again after boot, every time.
I tried running software center using console typing 'software-center', and result was this:

```
2017-10-04 13:52:00,663 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in 
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 143, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 74, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I googled about this, and most answer was about reinstalling, which is not helpful in this case.

---

Thanks for reading. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has stopped supporting **Ubuntu Software Center** after the release of **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. So, the default software center on 16.04 and its successors is **Gnome Software** (at least for now).

**Gnome Software**  has some disadvantages. Although, it may have a better look, it will not show all software available to the official repository, only the ones that are relatively popular. But, it supports some **snaps** (for example, PyCharm).

And about second problem, there might be some misconfigurations with your internet connection, as the actual problem  is:

**The maintainer contacted but no resolution and/or answer.**